# Delete the folder that is pointing to other location in ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, delete-file

[In this screen shot my 'Webapp' folder is pointing to other location how i remove and delete this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RefOn.png)

Answer (score 3):

it seems like a hard link to the pointed folder. 
One solution is to remove the pointed folder:

```
rm -r /home/asifjavedg3/couttalure/1412-DressingAphrodite/Webapp
```

Now you can remove the folder pointer:

```
rm -r Webapp
```

And create a new folder with the same name:

```
sudo mkdir Webapp
```

Answer (score 2):

Try these commands for deleting files.

> Commands for deleting files
>
> The terminal command for deleting file(s) is `rm`. The general format of this command is `rm [-f|i|I|q|R|r|v] file...`
>
> `rm` removes a file if you specify a correct path for it and if you don't, then it displays an error message and move on to the next file. Sometimes you may not have the write permissions for a file, in that case it asks you for confirmation. Type yes if you want to delete it.
>
> Source https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DeletingFiles (Read the warnings here as well.)

You can try Apache Tomcat 7 (open source web server) via `apt-get`.

`$sudo apt-get update`

`$sudo apt-get install tomcat7`

Answer yes at the prompt to install Tomcat. This will install Tomcat and its dependencies, such as Java, and it will also create the tomcat7 user. It also starts Tomcat with its default settings.

Full Apache Tomcat 7 installation steps found [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-apache-tomcat-7-on-ubuntu-14-04-via-apt-get).